# Android share SQLite over wifi or bluetooth

Tags: android, sqlite, bluetooth, wifi

Is it possible to share a Database between devices without an Internet connection?

What I want to do is something like this

- Device 1 Main Device, always on, shares the SQLite Database
- Device 2 Reads & Writes into the SQLite Database of Device 1
- Device 3 Reads & Writes into the SQLite Database of Device 1

All Devices are Running the same app. The distance is not more than 5 - 8 meter.

Is it possible? And if it is possible what is better Bluetooth or Wifi?

Comment: Sure it's possible, a SQLite database is essentially a file. A Bluetooth-based solution will probably be easier to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definetly possible. In your scenario device 1 would act as host and device 2 & 3 as clients.

The fact that you want to read from / write to a database is almost irrelevant. All you have to do is implement a request-answer system: Client sends a query, host evaluates and/or executes the query and sends the result back.

> And if it is possible what is better Bluetooth or Wifi?

There is no definite answer to that question. I would prefer wifi as it imposes fewer constraints on the pysical distance of the devices and works well with a request-answer system (http).